# Displaying output based on attribute value of xml tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<provinces>
 <name num="5">Alberta</name>
 <name num="3">British</name>
 <name num="1">Manitoba</name>
 <name num="4">New Brunswick</name>
 <name num="2">Newfoundland</name>
</provinces>
```

I want output as

```
1. Manitoba
2. Newfoundland  
3. British
4. New Brunswick
5. Alberta
```

I am using the following xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="provinces">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
    <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know this way of doing does not give my desired output but this is so far I got.

I want to position them based on the attribute "num" value how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to position them based on the attribute "num" value how do i do that??

This kind of manipulation is called *sorting*. Sorting the input elements inside `xsl:apply-templates` is what you need:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="name">
    <xsl:sort select="@num"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Also, to avoid getting all the text on a single line, output a newline character if the current `name` node is not the last one.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="provinces">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name">
        <xsl:sort select="@num" data-type="number"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(),'. ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Text Output**

```
1. Manitoba
2. Newfoundland
3. British
4. New Brunswick
5. Alberta
```

Comment: The `<xsl:sort select="@num"/>` should better be `<xsl:sort select="@num" data-type="number"/>`, to make sure the sorting is done numerically. Otherwise with more items `10` would end before `2`.